# Pop up appearing blank after JSON parse?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson, wms

My aim is to retrieve the attribute list of a WMS layer. The concept is to fetch it as JSON data, then parse it and display it in a pop up. I am using OpenLayers3 with local GeoServer and JavaScript.

When I enter the WMS request URL in browser, I get response as given below.

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"OSM_Grid_25000_include_hazard_line.60","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[623207.0023,1133268.8385],[609515.9426,1133223.6554],[609472.75,1147046.3421],[623158.4075,1147092.0522],[623207.0023,1133268.8385]]]]},"geometry_name":"the_geom","properties":{"OBJECTID_1":162,"OBJECTID_2":162,"OBJECTID":25925,"OSM_25K_IN":"C 43 K 3/SW","Map_No":39,"Map_KL_No":"KL 39"}}],"totalFeatures":"unknown","numberReturned":1,"timeStamp":"2019-09-19T12:06:17.336Z","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::32643"}}}
```

Here, I need the value of "Map_No" to be displayed inside the pop up. Hence I wrote the code given below.

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
            var view = map.getView();
            var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (map.getView().getResolution());
            var url = tiledOSM.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(evt.coordinate, view.getResolution(), view.getProjection(), {
                'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
                'PIXELRADIUS': 5,
                'FEATURE_COUNT': 10
            });
if (url) {
        var parser = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          jsonpCallback: 'parseResponse'
        }).then(function(response) {
          var result = parser.readFeatures(response);
          if (result.length) {
            var info = [];
            for (var i = 0, ii = result.length; i < ii; ++i) {
              info.push(result[i].get('Map_No'));
            }
            content.innerHTML = info.join(",");

          } 
        });
      }

      overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate); 
    });
```

When I run this code, the pop up is appearing blank. Since I am a beginner, I am not able to understand it.

Should I add any JavaScript reference link to make this code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popup was appearing blank because of CORS error and I fixed it by adding Moesif CORS extension to chrome browser. Now, the above code works as expected. Hence,I am marking this as answer.